# Why "Confirm your choices" pops up twice using cordova google-plus plugin?

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, google-signin

```
let params;
    if(this.platform.is('android')){
      params = {
        'webClientId': '77852...client id stuff..',
        'offline': true
      }
    }
    else{
      params={}
    }

this.googlePlus.login(params)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
}
)
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

this is the whole code I am using, If I call this code the following happens:

Firstly I have to decide which google Account I want to use, next it asks me to confirm my choice and press allow, after I pressed the button, the same menu pops up again and only after a second "allow" click I get the iDToken.

Why does the same menu pop up twice with the same content?

Comment: Did you found the solution ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are just using for login (doesnt required any serverAuthCode ) then pass 'offline': false

> let params;
>       if(this.platform.is('android')){
>         params = {
>           'webClientId': '77852...client id stuff..',
>           'offline': false
>         }
>       }
>       else{
>         params={}
>       }
>
> this.googlePlus.login(params)
>       .then(res => {
>         console.log(res); } ) .catch(err => console.error(err));

Answer (score 1):

There is post on the github page of the GooglePlus plugin =>
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/675

Comment: did any one find the solution ??

Comment: For now still pending.

Comment: This issue happened to my so far. Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: The comment above helped me